# Configure Laravel .1 htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I've installed Laravel 5.1 and try to configure it on a shared hosting.
I've added index.php file in project root and .htaccess file in public folder but still getting:

`500 Internal server Error`

I've run:
`composer install`.

I've added in `.env`file database configuration.

My project folder is named `cms`.

Then I tried to change `.htaccess file` in `public directory` like that:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cms/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

My `.htaccess file` in `project root` is:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       # Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /cms/
#    RewriteBase /home/crewjobe/public_html/
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
#    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
#    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

I have index.php file in both project root and public directory.
Index.php in public directory is installed from laravel.
Index.php file in project root is:

```html
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

//This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.' /public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.' /public/index.php';
```

Where I am wrong? Is there a standart way to make configuration when make a fresh install of Laravel? Thanks.

Comment: I've never see nested IF in .htaccess.. not sure that's the problem but it does look odd. Suggest moving this outside the `if mod_rewrite' block
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       # Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

Comment: This is created with laravel installation in this way..I changed a little the other part

Comment: How do you know that the issue is related to `.htaccess`? Error 500 suggests some PHP error. Do you have an `error.log` on your `public` or `public_html` directories on the shared host? Also, add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the `index.php` and check if you have a detailed error

Comment: I checked server error log and there is message: ""/path/to/cms1" is writeable by group" and " client denied by server configuration: /path/to/public_html/domain_name/.htaccess"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @milz, after I checked server error log and found these messages:

`path/to/project/folder/  is writeable by group`

and searched for the problem, I found this solution:
[Solution](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/5012/solved-internal-server-error-softexception-in-application-cpp-256-file-public-htmlindex-php-is-writeable-by-group)

I changed project folder permissions to `0644` and also project/public folder too and it's fine now.